# Reduce возвращает undefined

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код в котором **reduce** переберает масив **allPixel** и возващает координаты подходящего пикселя. Сначала все хорошо но как **reduce** идёт по второму кругу **allCoordinates** становиться undefined а именно после  return.

Как я понял когда **reduce** идёт по второму кругу **allCoordinates** присваивается координаты **"0,0 1,0"** (allCoordinates = "0,0 1,0") и из-за этого возникает проблема.

Нужно неизменять **allCoordinates** а присваивать изменения с return какой нибудь переменной, но не знаю как это сделать.

```
function definePoints (allPixel) { // allPixel = Array(256)
        let points = allPixel.reduce((allCoordinates, coordinates) => {

            let allCoordinatesColor =   JSON.stringify(allCoordinates.color) //allCoordinatesColor = "{"red":0,"blue":0,"green":0,"alpha":0}", allCoordinates = {x: 0, y: 0, color: {…}}

            let coordinatesColor    =   JSON.stringify(coordinates.color) //coordinatesColor = "{"red":0,"blue":0,"green":0,"alpha":0}", coordinates = {x: 1, y: 0, color: {…}}


            if (allCoordinatesColor === coordinatesColor)  //allCoordinatesColor = "{"red":0,"blue":0,"green":0,"alpha":0}", coordinatesColor = "{"red":0,"blue":0,"green":0,"alpha":0}"

                {return `${allCoordinates.x},${allCoordinates.y} ${+coordinates.x},${+coordinates.y}`} //allCoordinatesColor = "{"red":0,"blue":0,"green":0,"alpha":0}", coordinatesColor = "{"red":0,"blue":0,"green":0,"alpha":0}"


            return allCoordinates
        })
        console.log(points)
    }
```

В данном примере массив состоит с 256 объектов тоесть 256 писелей:

```
const pixelData = {
    x   : pixelX, // 0
    y   : pixelY, // 0
    color : {
        red     : +imgData.data[i], // 0
        blue    : +imgData.data[i+1], // 0
        green   : +imgData.data[i+2], // 0
        alpha   : +imgData.data[i+3] * 0.00392156862745098 // 0
    }
}
```

Здесь прозрачный пиксель с нулевыми координатами.

Comment: Из блока `if` возвращается строка `x,y x,y`. На следующем цикле эта строка используется как объект `allCoordinates.color`, это как???

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg вот я сам не знаю (●__●)

Comment: "_вот я сам не знаю _"(с), так и никто не знает. По этому отрывку кода нет возможности определить задачу.

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg изменил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Проблема наверно в том, что третей строке ты обращаешься к свойству `color`

```
let allCoordinatesColor =   JSON.stringify(allCoordinates.color)
```

Но после того, как сработает конструкция `if`

```
if (allCoordinatesColor === coordinatesColor)
```

Та возвращаешь не объект, а строку, в которой нет свойства `color`.

Тебе нужно внимательно изучить документацию по `.reduce()`.

[Ссылка на документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Судя по задаче, тебе нужно отфильтровать массив. Для этого лучше использовать метод `.filter()`.